# How to use tagit with knockout

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, tag-it

i am using http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/ in my code
how to bind with viewmodel

html

```
<ul data-bind='jqueryui: "tagit",foreach: Tags' >
            <li class="tagit-choice ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-all" data-bind='with: $data'>
                <span class="tagit-label" data-bind='text: $data'></span>
                <a class="tagit-close">
                    <span class="text-icon">&times;</span>
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span>
                </a>
                <input type="hidden" name="item[tags][]" data-bind='value: $data'  style="display: none;">
            </li>
            </ul>
```

Js code

```
function AppViewModel() {
var self = this;

function Tag(data) {
            this.Name = data;
        }

self.Tags = ko.observableArray([
            new Tag('red'),
            new Tag('blue'),
            new Tag('green')
        ]);
 }

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks Cedric no need to write custom binder

i solve this way [link](http://jsfiddle.net/MHVas/8/)

```
$("#mytags").tagit({
 availableTags: JSON.parse(ko.toJSON(_.pluck(AppViewModel.Tags, 'Name'))),
 onTagAdded: function (event, tagval) {
                    //on every add add with id if tag exist in system
                    var newtag = $(tagval).children('span.tagit-label').html();
                    var temp = _.find(AppViewModel.Tags, function (item) { return item.Name() == newtag; });
                    if (temp) {
                            AppViewModel().SelectedTags.push( Tag({ 'Id': temp.Id(), "Name": newtag} ));
                    }
                    else {
                            AppViewModel().SelectedTags.push( Tag({ "Name": newtag} ));
                    }

                },
onTagRemoved: function (event, tagval) {
                    // do something special
                    var tempTag = $(tagval).children('span.tagit-label').html();
                    AppViewModel().SelectedTags.remove(_.find(SelectedTags(), function (item) { return item.Name == tempTag; }));
                }});
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a another binding handler for knockout based on Robert Wagner's answer, since i didnt feel that it was dynamic enough:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.tagit = {
//https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var bind = function () {
        valueAccessor().tags($(element).tagit("assignedTags"));
    };

    var options = $.extend({
        allowSpaces: false,
        caseSensitive: false,
        showAutocompleteOnFocus: true,
        afterTagAdded: function(t,s) { bind(); },
        afterTagRemoved: function(t,s) { bind(); },
        placeholderText: "",
        preprocessTag: function () { },
        beforeTagAdded: function (evt, tag) {
            if (tag.tagLabel.length == 0 || tag.tagLabel.toLowerCase() === options.placeholderText.toLowerCase()) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }, valueAccessor().options || {});

    var tags = valueAccessor()["autocomplete"];
    if (tags)
        $.extend(options, {
            autocomplete: $.extend({ source: tags.source, delay: 0, minLength: 0 },tags)
        });

    $(element).tagit(options);
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    var tags = value.tags();
    $(element).tagit("removeAll");
    for (var x = 0; x < tags.length; x++) {
        $(element).tagit("createTag", tags[x]);
    }
}
};
```

My preprocess and autocompleter functions:

```
self.TagAutocompleter = function (d, ds) {
    DataMethod.postData("tag/autocomplete", d, function (data) {
        ds(ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (t) { return t.Tag; }));
    });
};

self.TagProcessor = function (tag) {
    return tag.toLowerCase().replace("#", '');
};
```

And use in html:

```
<ul data-bind="tagit:{tags:Tags, autocomplete:{source:TagAutocompleter, delay:250, minLength: 2}, options:{preprocessTag: TagProcessor}}">
</ul>
```

Comment: Also I Fixed an error in the update part, so it can use data that is in the observable from the start

Comment: Can you include a code snippet for TagAutocompleter and TagProcessor?

Comment: I've updated the original answer with those + a minor update :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a custom binding https://gist.github.com/droyad/6136446

```
ko.bindingHandlers.tags = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

        var bind = function() {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).tagit("assignedTags").join(','));
        };

        var options = {
            allowSpaces: true,
            caseSensitive: false,
            showAutocompleteOnFocus: true,
            afterTagAdded: bind,
            afterTagRemoved: bind
        };

        var tags = allBindingsAccessor()["tagsSource"];
        if (tags)
            $.extend(options, {                
                autocomplete: { source: tags, delay: 0, minLength: 0 }
            });

        $(element).tagit(options);
        $(element).data('uiTagit').tagInput.css("width", "50px");
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var tags = value.split(',');
        $(element).tagit("removeAll");
        for (var x = 0; x < tags.length; x++) {
            $(element).tagit("createTag", tags[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I write a simple fiddle where it's work. It's construct component with de tag list.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/muadhib/MHVas/2/)

But it's not a two ways binding.
If you wan't to do that i advise you to create a custom binder where it call the knockout's foreach model binder .  [See information to Custom model binders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html)

On the init function, you need to subscibe to tags changes in knockout observableArray for update the control. And you need to subscribe to onTagAdded event and onTagRemoved event.

There is a sample code where i extend the foreach component:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.extendForeach = {
    makeForeachValueAccessor: function (valueAccessor) {
         return function () {

            if ((!bindingValue) || typeof bindingValue.length == "number"){
                bindingValue = {
                    data : bindingValue
                }
            }

            return {
                'data': bindingValue['data'],
                'afterAdd': bindingValue['afterAdd'],
                'beforeRemove': bindingValue['beforeRemove'],
                'afterRender': bindingValue['afterRender'],
            };
        };
    },

    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var newValAccess = ko.bindingHandlers.extendForeach.makeForeachValueAccessor(valueAccessor);
        return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, newValAccess, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    },

    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var newValAccess = ko.bindingHandlers.extendForeach.makeForeachValueAccessor(valueAccessor);
        return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, newValAccess, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

I hope this help you.